# How to set up connect-mongo (or use sessions in mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using ExpressJS and Mongoose.

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var sessionStore = new MongoStore({db: 'myappsession'});

app.use(express.session({ secret: "myappsecret", store:sessionStore }));
```

This results in an "MongoError: Error: unauthorized db". I suppose I would need to pass it my log-in credentials. I also have,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('<omitted username, password and address>', 'myappsession');
```

I am guessing connect-mongo needs this information to log into my database to create the session store?

How do I pass connect-mongo the log-in information? Or am I doing this wrongly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, since I am already actively using Mongoose, I ended up using a solution for Mongoose.

**1. Install session-mongoose**

https://github.com/donpark/session-mongoose

**2. Use this tutorial as a guide.**

http://mikevalstar.com/Blog/107/Coding_with_Nodejs_Part_31_Mongoose_Sessions

**3. In particular, I had problem with this line of the tutorial.**

```
url: "mongodb://localhost/mv"
```

This should be something like,

```
url: "username:password@url/testdatabase"
```

Sessions are then stored in the database named ""testdatabase" in the collection "sessions".

I hope this answer help someone avoid some frustration. :)

Comment: Care to explain why this is not a good solution? I am actually using this in my app.

Comment: @ktkaushik - that tutorial used to work. You can google for "Coding_with_Nodejs_Part_31_Mongoose_Sessions" and access a cached version.

Comment: Thank you for this. I easily replaced connect-mongodb with session-mongoose, which doesn't have the startup issue I observed with both connect-mongodb and connect-mongo.

Comment: @Aaron - I am glad it helped. Very litte beginner guides out there for node.js stuff. You are welcome.

Comment: @Legendre Agreed, the state of Node.js training information is lacking. It doesn't help that Node (and many NPM modules) are rapidly evolving, so that year-old information is often outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a MongoDB URI. Look at the docs here:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

So given you are connecting to a single server, simply use:

```
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1]', 'myappsession');
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! But I found another solution for mongoose. Will share it by  writing my own answer later.